# Где достать Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Где достать библиотеки для использования Roslyn? Смотрел примеры на этом сайте: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2011/12/02/introduction-to-the-roslyn-scripting-api/ Но не могу найти библиотеки для использования. Подскажите, где их можно достать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Платформа Roslyn распространяется в виде двух nuget-пакетов [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis) (API) и [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers) (компиляторы).
Исходный код платформы доступен на [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn).

Установить можно так, используя консоль менеджера пакетов:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis
```